# 'Kind' of confused about forall in type-indexed GADTs

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I've run into an odd situation in GHC 8.0.1 with kind-indexed (?) GADTs where introducing foralls in the type vs kind signatures produces different type-checking behaviors.

Consider the following data types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType, GADTs, ExplicitForAll #-}
-- Same thing happens when we replace ExplicitForAll with ScopedTypeVariables

import Data.Kind

data F (k :: * -> *) where

data G :: F k -> * where
  G :: G x
```

This data type compiles just fine. However, if we want to specify the kind of `x` in the constructor `G`, we get a type error.

```
data H :: F k -> * where
  H :: forall k' (x :: F k'). H x
```

The error message is

> ```
> • Kind variable ‘k’ is implicitly bound in datatype
>   ‘H’, but does not appear as the kind of any
>   of its type variables. Perhaps you meant
>   to bind it (with TypeInType) explicitly somewhere?
> • In the data declaration for ‘H’
> ```

If we add the `forall` to the kind signature (with or without the `forall` in the constructor), there is no error.

```
data I :: forall k. F k -> * where
  I :: I x

data J :: forall k. F k -> * where
  J :: forall k' (x :: F k'). J x
```

What's going on?

Comment: truly excellent pun. A+

Comment: It looks as if the former declares `F k` to be fixed for the whole declaration, while the latter allows `H` to be used in its own declaration at different kinds. I.e. it allows polykinded recursion. Could be similar to the "parameters vs indices" distinction in inductive types (as in Agda/Coq).

Comment: Looks like this might be a (recently fixed) compiler bug.  I can duplicate your error message with "ghc-8.0.1" but it compiles fine with "ghc-8.0.1.20161117", the latest version that "stack" decided to install for me (and which seems to be a release candidate for 8.0.2).

Comment: @chi: I don't think that's it, for two reasons.  First, because you can't refer to `k` in the constructor: `data H' :: F k -> * where H' :: forall (x :: F k). H' x` produces the same error as `H`.  And second, because my understanding is that GHC doesn't have a parameter/index distinction, not even with TypeInType :-)

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky, GHC does make that distinction, but it's not syntactic. Rather, it infers whether an argument is "GADT-like" (an index) or not (a parameter).

Comment: @dfeuer: My understanding is that this is a surface Haskell thing only though, right?  "Parameters" get translated to Core in the boring way, and "GADT-like" arguments get translated to Core as an equality.  So you still "only have parameters", in a certain sense.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky, I think you're right that they're only in Haskell and not Core. They affect role inference, at least. Not sure what else.

Comment: Seems like this may be related to visibility: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DependentHaskell/Phase1#Visibilitychangesintypes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of `TypeInType` here. K. A. Buhr gets it right above; this is just a bug. It's fixed in HEAD.

For the overly curious: this error message is meant to eliminate definitions like

```
data J = forall (a :: k). MkJ (Proxy a)
```

where

```
data Proxy (a :: k) = Proxy
```

can be imported from `Data.Proxy`. When declaring a datatype in Haskell98-style syntax, any existentially quantified variables must be explicitly brought into scope with a `forall`. But `k` is never brought into scope explicitly; it is just used in the kind of `a`. So that means that `k` should be universally quantified (in other words, it should be an invisible parameter to `J`, like the `k` parameter to `Proxy`)... but then when we write `J`, there is no way to determine what `k` should be, so it would always be ambiguous. (In contrast, we can discover the choice for the `k` parameter to `Proxy` by looking at `a`'s kind.)

This definition for `J` is disallowed in 8.0.1 and in HEAD.